# Spring data mongoDb Configuration explaination

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc

I just started learning spring and mongoDb integration, but I didn't catch how the configuration should look properly.

I use official spring [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo-template.instantiating) using java config examples.

here in s[ection 9.3](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.mongo-java-config) is said that I can init `MongoFactoryBean` and then use it throw `@Autowired` annotation.

But then in [section 9.3.4](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.mongo-db-factory-java) we see initialization of beans using `new Mongo()`.

Question: can I use '@Autowired Mongo mongo' in case of `new Mongo()`? And should I have two separate configurations or I use configuration like in [section 9.4.1](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo-template.instantiating).

Can someone explain me in easier words how to make configuration?

Comment: You can find here similar discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21629500/difference-between-mongofactorybean-and-simplemongodbfactory